# MVC3 Membership hybrid AD and Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I have a MVC3 site which needs users to be able to login in the domain\user password style and user password style.  One against AD and the other against a EF Table.  How can I go about creating a hybrid membership provider?  Has anyone successfully done this and has best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about writing an own MembershipProvider implementation and forward to the other two providers?

Comment: That's what I was going to do but wanted to know if there is a way to integrate a default AD membership provider into the custom one, and any best practices.